# Turn off PC if bluetooth device is disconnected (proximity) or loses connection

Tags: windows, windows-10, security, bluetooth

Is there such software, I've looked into Windows security features for such an option and it doesn't exist. I have found that you can unlock your PC with your Bluetooth device but can't shut it down if you leave your PC for instance.

My idea is as follows, I have a smartwatch *(or a phone)* and I keep it on me the whole time. I would like to just leave my PC and if my Bluetooth (watch) disconnects from my PC I would like it to shutdown.

- if Bluetooth device disconnects > **turn off PC**

Why? Many times I forget to turn off my computer either at work or at home and as I wear my watch or have my phone on, I can just connect it over with Bluetooth and if I leave for whatever reason it can just shut down *(or hibernate)*

- I have tried basic google search for such software but haven't found one.

Answer (score 1):

That feature, [Dynamic Lock](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/windows-10-dynamic-lock-bluetooth-range/), to automatically lock the PC when Bluetooth connection is lost, is built into Windows 10 April Creator's update. That, combined with a timeout to shut the PC with inactivity in Power Options, should do what you want.

[image: Hibernate Delay]

If *Hibernate*, which *completely* shuts the PC (as opposed to *Sleep*, which uses some power), is not in your Power Options menu, enable it [by clicking *Change settings that are currently unavailable*](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7445-add-remove-hibernate-power-menu-windows-10-a.html), or [in an elevated CMD prompt](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/108391-add-remove-hibernate-after-power-options-windows.html):

```
powercfg -attributes SUB_SLEEP 9d7815a6-7ee4-497e-8888-515a05f02364 -ATTRIB_HIDE
```

That said, there are some issues:

1. There's a 30 second delay, so that temporary loss of connection doesn't shut the PC accidentally. "If someone hops onto your PC while it's unlocked, Dynamic Lock won't engage at all."
2. There's no automatic *unlock*.
3. Bluetooth-Windows connections may be a bit flaky, requiring repeated connection.

Comment: Awesome suggestion, I will test it out and hopefully this will be it. I need to know if this can be actually used. Any chance I can make it shutdown, not just hibernate?

Comment: I don't mind it sleeping for instance for like 10-minutes but I'd like it to shut down after that. Any chance for something like this? Why? Sleep makes your computer vulnerable to many different attacks, extracting keys from RAM and so on, many use BitLocker or similar technologies and are safe only on full shutdown.

Comment: Hibernate **completely** shuts the PC. See the illustration above.

Comment: Oh I didnt know that the issue is I don't even have this option, let me send a screenshot.
https://prnt.sc/wfh9tm